# jVector map - selecting/deselecting regions

Tags: jquery, jvectormap

I have a list of countries in a ul and when they are clicked I am trying to highlight them on the map - the problem I have is when another country is clicked I want to deselect all the countries and only highlight this one. At the moment if you click on another country they just stay selected, im presuming im doing something wrong when using clearSelectedRegions(); on the below.

Or maybe I am completely over complicating the whole thing?

```
$('ul').on('click', 'a:first-child', function (event) {
    var elem = event.target,
        evtype = event.type,
        cntrycode = findRegion(mapObj2.regions, $(elem).text());

    if (evtype === 'click') {
        mapObj2.clearSelectedRegions();
        mapObj2.regions[cntrycode].element.setHovered(true);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wWFG2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're over complicating the whole thing, just set [regionsSelectableOne](http://jvectormap.com/documentation/javascript-api-v1/jvm-worldmap/) option to true and use setSelectedRegions instead of setHovered, which has nothing to do with selected state. See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wWFG2/1/):

```
if (evtype === 'click') {
    mapObj2.clearSelectedRegions();
    mapObj2.setSelectedRegions([cntrycode]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply - but regionsSelectableOne is already set to true in the jsfiddle ?